# Assimp silently fails to calculate tangent space

Tags: c++, assimp

I'm using Assimp to load models to use for my application. Generally I'm interested in having tangent space - normals, tangents and bitangets. There is an option for assimp to calculate them:

```
// Calculates the tangents and bitangents for the imported meshes. 
aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace = 0x1
```

However this does nothing in my case. The mesh I'm trying to import has normals, but no tangents and bitangents. This is how I read my files:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;

const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(myFile,
    aiProcess_Triangulate |
    aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
    aiProcess_OptimizeGraph |
    aiProcess_OptimizeMeshes |
    aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals |
    aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);

OutputDebugStringA(importer.GetErrorString());

aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[0];

if (!mesh->HasNormals() || !mesh->HasPositions() || !mesh->HasFaces() || !mesh->HasTangentsAndBitangents())
    return false;
```

If I break in this code, the "mesh" ptr has normals, but tangets and bitangents are null.

And nothing is output from 'importer.GetErrorString()'

Comment: Tangent space requires texture coordinates for vertices . Do you have those?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie  you mean UV coordinates then yes. I even threw in 'aiProcess_GenUVCoords' for good measure - did not help with this case though